# VLOOKUP which key is not the first column and multi conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a key **Hero Name** with their **Class** in SheetC. I have a list of **Hero Name** in SheetA with their Name and the Rarity of their Weapon. 
In SheetB I have a list of **Weapon Name** based on the **Rarity** and the Class of the weapon.
What I need is to lookup for the **Weapon Name** that the Heroes wear in SheetA by using their Class in either column C(Class1) or D(Class2) in a range of SheetB, and Rarity of their weapon in SheetA.

There is another condition that the value must match to a key "Rarity" in Colum B(Rarity).
Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12uDJXmqhKblClssdTEewgcYup3O1MJ389VKf670t5sM/edit#gid=1639375076

The problem is Class 1 and 2 is not the first column, Hero Name is in SheetC, and there are multiple conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B&A2:A, 
 {SheetB!B2:B&SheetB!C2:C, SheetB!A2:A; 
  SheetB!B2:B&SheetB!D2:D, SheetB!A2:A}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. It works. But there is a solution if I have to find the value of Class column in another sheet by using Vlookup in Column C(Weapon Name)?

Comment: Ex: I hide the column Class in SheetA and I must find it in SheetC by using Hero Name.

Comment: not sure I understand.... pls edit your sheet and include example of desired output

Comment: Edited, sorry for the confusion.